# How does Office 2013's document locking work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, lock

I've run into a couple of problems with files being locked/unlocked in Office 2013 in my company.

1. documents (Word/Excel files, mostly) are getting unlocked if not regularly saved. A user has a server file open for an hour, and the system will no longer prevent another user from opening and saving that file. This needs to not happen, but I have no idea how to fix it, other than telling users to save more frequently (which they should anyways)
2. Documents are inconsistently refusing to show the name of the person who has locked them, instead not showing any name

Both of these problems are pretty tricky for me, because I don't know how Office 2013's document locking actually works.

Can anyone help me resolve these problems? Or explain how document locking actually works? Attempts to find a good explanation have been drowned out by the huge number of people who, working alone on a home PC, end up locking themselves out of their own files by mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi J, is this a real filesever or actually a share to a directory in SharePoint?

Comment: Hi Ring, it is a real fileserver.